# Problema para determinar la funcion de un buleano en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, booleano

Tengo una duda con respecto a un código que encontré en internet para resolver un algoritmo.

Mi duda es la siguiente: El código que voy a pasar a continuación sirve para determinar si un numero es o no primo, mi duda es: porque si yo quito el `return False` y pongo como parámetro el numero `27` (por ejemplo), la consola me arroja como resultado el `3`, el `9` y además me arroja el `print` que esta afuera del ciclo `for`

Si por otro lado agrego el `return False` este cumple una función de "detener el código apenas se cumple la condición por primera vez" como si fuera un break, entonces la consola me arroja solamente el `3` (que es el primer numero que cumple la condición) y no arroja tampoco el `print` que esta fuera del ciclo `for`

```
def es_primo(numero):
    for n in range(2, numero):
        if numero % n == 0:
            print(f"{numero} No es primo {n} es su divisor")
            return False # **<---- ESTE ES EL CODIGO DE LA DISCORDIA JJA** 

    print(f"{numero} Es primo")
    return True

es_primo(27)
```

DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS DE ANTE MANO!!!

Answer (score 1):

El `return False` termina la ejecución al encontrar el primer divisor.

Si lo quitas, sigue buscando todos los divisores, e imprimiendolos dentro del ciclo.

Luego que el ciclo `for` termina, se ejecutan las instrucciones restantes de la función, que imprimen `27 es primo`.

Comment: Entiendo que el return false termina la ejecucion al encontrar el primer divisor, lo que no entiendo es porque termina la ejecucion si simplemente es un buleano. Esta cumpliendo una funcion similar al -break-. No entiendo porque un buleano puede terminar la ejecucion de un ciclo for

Comment: No es el booleano, es el `return`.

Comment: Acabo de ver que si le dejo el return solo y le saco el buleano, me sigue funcionando bien. Entonces mi duda es  porque el return me termina el ciclo? Tenia entendido que los return servian para devolver un valor, no que podian usarse solos para detener un ciclo

Comment: El `return` termina la función, desde donde quieras que la llames. Opcionalmente puedes retornar un valor, pero no es obligación.

Answer (score 1):

Es simplemente una forma más corta de escribir este código:

```
def es_primo(numero):
    el_num_es_primo = True
    for n in range(2, numero):
        if numero % n == 0:
            print(f"{numero} No es primo {n} es su divisor")
            el_num_es_primo = False
            break
    if el_num_es_primo:
        print(f"{numero} Es primo")
    
    return el_num_es_primo # <-- Esta funcion siempre termina aqui

es_primo(27)
```

En este caso hay un solo `return`, así que la lógica está diseñada para salir por ahí. Pero para que funcione bien, se necesita una variable auxiliar que transporte el resultado por la función, esta es `el_num_es_primo`.

Sin embargo, un programador un poco más experto no necesita un código tan formal. Suficiente es con saber que si entró al `if` anidado del `for`, ya se sabe que el número no es primo así que el `return` mata la ejecución de la función y devuelve `False`. Si NUNCA entra a ese `if`, entonces el ciclo `for` se termina normalmente y se ejecuta lo que está debajo.

Preguntarás, ¿por qué devuelve `False` o `True`?. Es para poder usar ese valor retornado más adelante en el código, pero en tu caso no lo estás usando.

Si llamas la función así:

```
resultado = es_primo(27) # Imprime: 27 No es primo 3 es su divisor
print(resultado) # <-- Imprime: False
```

Ahora bien, entiendo el motivo de tu confusión, y es que esa función está *mal diseñada*. Una función debe procesar algo y retornar (o no) el resultado. No debe hacer impresiones en medio, a menos que se trate de una función de imprimir, donde ese sea su objetivo.

Dicho eso, ese programa debería ser algo así:

```
def es_primo(numero):
    for n in range(2, numero):
        if numero % n == 0:
            return False
    return True

num = 27
if es_primo(num):
    print(f"{num} Es primo")
else:
    print(f"{num} No es primo")
```

Ahora sí estás utilizando el valor retornado, y como ves la programación resulta de forma natural, como si estuvieras conversando con el intérprete.

---

Sé que en la función que pones de ejemplo imprime otro valor, el **primer divisor** en caso de que no sea primo. Sin embargo, como expuse arriba, la función debe hacer una sola cosa. La función se llama `es_primo()` o sea, ¿es primo o no es primo?. No se llama `primer_divisor()`.

Por supuesto, se podría hacer que retorne ambas cosas (si es primo o no y su primer divisor) haciendo un pequeño cambio:

```
def es_primo(numero):
    for n in range(2, numero):
        if numero % n == 0:
            return [False, n]
    return [True, None]

num = 27
resultado, divisor = es_primo(num) # <-- La lista se desempaca en estas 2 variables
if resultado:
    print(f"{num} Es primo")
else:
    print(f"{numero} No es primo {divisor} es su divisor")
```

No es lo usual, pero sigue siendo un código más natural que el que se expone en tu problema.